# Generate Checksum for directories using Ant build command

Tags: windows, ant, checksum

I tried to generate the [checksum](/questions/tagged/checksum) for directory using [ant](/questions/tagged/ant).

I have tried the below command, but it generates recursively inside each folder for each file.

```
<target name="default" depends="">
    <echo message="Generating Checksum for each environment" />
    <checksum todir="${target.output.dir}" format="MD5SUM" >
        <fileset dir="${target.output.dir}" />
    </checksum>
</target>
```

I just want to generate one `checksum` for particular directory using `Ant` command. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `totalproperty` attribute. As per [the documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/checksum.html) this property `will hold a checksum of all the checksums and file paths`.

e.g.

```
<target name="hash">
  <checksum todir="x" format="MD5SUM" totalproperty="sum.of.all">
    <fileset dir="x"/>
  </checksum>
  <echo>${sum.of.all}</echo>
</target>
```

Some other general notes.

- This is not idempotent. Each time you run it you will get a new value because it includes the previous hash file in the new hash (and then writes a new hash file). I suggest that you change the `todir` attribute to point elsewhere
- It's a good idea to name your targets meaningfully. See [this great article by Martin Fowler for some naming ideas](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/OutputBuildTarget.html)
- You don't need the `depends` attribute if there's no dependency.

Comment: Thanks alot :) it works. Well, one more question. How to use `SHA-256` format ?

Comment: Ant is probably calling `MessageDigest.getInstance(format)` under the covers. This means you will need to have installed a security provider that supports the format you want. Have you tried it? If it doesn't work, then you should install a provider (such as http://bouncycastle.org/ into your JRE).