# Hash a property value using Ant checksum

Tags: hash, ant, md5

I'd like to hash a property value using MD5 that I get from a file and then store it in existing XML file as a property value.

1. I get some string and store it in a property: "Example"
2. Make MD5 from it: `1A79A4D60DE6718E8E5B326E338AE533`
3. Store it in XML:

   ```
   .....
    <data prop="1A79A4D60DE6718E8E5B326E338AE533" />
   .....
   ```

Can I do it? If yes can you post an example?

Comment: The `<checksum>` task can create MD5 hashes. You can then use `<echo>` to create XML containing the hash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate Checksum for directories using Ant build command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599216/generate-checksum-for-directories-using-ant-build-command)